# Does DayZ run on linux?

Tags: linux, dayz-2012

Can I run the DayZ mod on linux? If it matters, I'm on Arch Linux 64bit. Their website is not at all clear.

Comment: Isn't the base game, Arma II, Windows only? Or are you planning on running a VM or something?

Comment: @Kotsu: I don't know, that's why I'm asking. I've never played that game. If that's what the case is, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DayZ is a mod for [ArmA II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArmA_II), which is a Windows only game.  You must own and your computer must be capable of playing ArmA II (specifically, its expansion ArmA II: Combined Operations, which includes the main game and a later expansion) in order to play DayZ.  So, unfortunately, it cannot be played on a Linux box.

Comment: That's unfortunate.

Comment: The wine appdb also rates arma2 as "garbage", so this is unlikely to work better in the near future: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10054

Comment: Actually, it rates the current version of Combined Operations as Bronze but "Consider as 'Silver' for patched wine". Haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Actually running Arma2 Client on linux works for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking if you can run a private hive DayZ *server* on Linux, then the answer is yes. You have to run it with wine, but it can be done. You cannot however run the game client on Linux.

Comment: I was asking about the client.